# How to add left and right margins in constraint layout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I have created an image view programmatically, and added it to constraint layout. Now i want to add margins from left and right of the `imageView.`

This is what i did.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
constraintLayout.addView(imageView);

//Convert DP to PX
int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                                             10,
                                             getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

//Loading image from URL by using Picasso.        
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
       .load(imageURL)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.card_loading)
       .fit()
       .centerCrop()
       .into(imageView);

imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

//Created Constraint Set.
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(constraintLayout);      
set.constrainWidth(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);

set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, eventsViewPager.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, margin);

set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, margin);

set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, margin);
```

Now the issue is that it creates margin from top, but no margin is added from left and right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `ConstraintSet.START` and `ConstraintSet.END` instead of `ConstraintSet.LEFT` and `ConstraintSet.RIGHT` . This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks :) This fixed the problem

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: don't forget to call `set.applyTo(...)` at the end